# subscribing an observableArray to a computed

Tags: javascript, knockout.js

I have an object that is constructed upon a table row from the database. It has all the properties that are found in that entry plus several ko.computed that are the middle layer between the entry fields and what is displayed. I need them to be able translate foreign keys for some field values.

The problem is the following: One of the properties is an ID for a string. I retrieve that ID with the computed. Now in the computed will have a value that looks like this: *'option1|option2|option3|option4'*

I want the user to be able to change the options, add new ones or swap them around, but I also need to monitor what the user is doing(at least when he adds, removes or moves one property around). Hence, I have created an observable array that I will bind in a way that would allow me to monitor user's actions. Then the array will subscribe to the computed so it would update the value in the database as well.

Some of the code:

```
function Control(field) {
    var self = this;
    self.entry = field;  // database entry
    self.choices = ko.observableArray();
    self.ctrlType = ko.computed({
        read: function () {
           ...
        },
        write: function (value) {
            if (value) {
                ...
            }
        },
        owner: self
    });
    self.resolvedPropriety = ko.computed({
        read: function () {
            if (self.ctrlType()) {
                var options = str.split('|');
                self.choices(createObservablesFromArrayElements(options));
        return str;
            }
            else {
                return '';
            }
        },
        write: function (value) {
            if (value === '') {
                //delete entry      
            }
            else {
                    //modify entry
            }
        },
        deferEvaluation: true,
        owner: self
    });
    self.choices.subscribe(function (newValue) {
        if (newValue.length !== 0) {
            var newStr = '';
            $.each(newValue, function (id, el) {
                newStr += el.name() + '|';
            });
            newStr = newStr.substring(0, newStr.lastIndexOf("|"));
            if (self.resolvedPropriety.peek() !== newStr) {
                self.resolvedPropriety(newStr);
            }
        }
    });
self.addChoice = function () {
    //user added an option
        self.choices.push({ name: ko.observable('new choice') });
    };
    self.removeChoice = function (data) {
    //user removed an option
        if (data) {
            self.choices.remove(data);
        }
    };
    ...
}
```

This combination works, but not as I want to. It is a cyclic behavior and it triggers too many times. This is giving some overload on the user's actions because there are a lot of requests to the database.

What am I missing? Or is there a better way of doing it?

Comment: what is the implementation of `ctrlType.read` that would make `if (self.ctrlType())` pass/fail? What is `ctrlType` bound to in the html?

Comment: If you don't want the DB to be called until the user's changes are ready, then you will need to build in some form of submit button or non-data-changes based event to replace the cyclic subscription. Or, break up the functionality into separate UI elements. Seems like a lot of functionality is being squeezed into whatever `html` is bound to `choices`. Supplying the `html` would help.

Comment: self.ctrlType() is just saying if the entity contains multiple values or not (true/false). Some entities may have choices, some not.  If there are no choices the self.resolvedPropriety() will be just an empty string and the observableArray will not be initialized or what I described above...

Answer (score 0):

Quote from  [knockout computed observable documentation](http://knockoutjs.com/documentation/computedObservables.html)

> ... it doesn’t make sense to include cycles in your dependency chains.

The basic functionality I interpreted from the post:

- Based on a field selection, display a list of properties/options
- Have the ability to edit said property/option
- Have the ability to add property/option
- Have the ability to delete property/option
- Have the ability to sort properties/options (its there, you have to click on the end/edge of the text field)
- Have the ability to save changes

As such, I have provided a skeleton example of the functionality, except the last one, you described @[JSfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/6AZgd/4/) The ability to apply the changes to the database can be addressed in several ways; None of which, unless you are willing to sacrifice the connection overhead, should include a computed or subscription on any changing data. By formatting the data (all of which I assumed could be collected in one service call) into a nice nested observable view model and passing the appropriate observables around, you can exclude the need for any `ko.computed`.

**JS**:

```
 var viewModel = {
 availableFields : ko.observableArray([
    ko.observable({fieldId: 'Field1', 
                   properties: ko.observableArray([{propertyName: "Property 1.1"}])}),
    ko.observable({fieldId: 'Field2', 
                   properties: ko.observableArray([{propertyName:"Property 2.1"}, 
                                                   {propertyName:"Property 2.2"}])})]),

 selectedField: ko.observable(),

 addProperty: function() {
    var propertyCount = this.selectedField().properties().length;

    this.selectedField().properties.push({propertyName: "Property " + propertyCount})
 },
};

ko.applyBindings(viewModel);
$("#field-properties-list").sortable({
   update: function (event, ui) {
   //jquery sort doesnt affect underlying array so we have to do it manually          
   var children = ui.item.parent().children();
   var propertiesOrderChanges = [];
   for (var i = 0; i < children.length; ++i) {
     var child = children[i];
     var item = ko.dataFor(child);
     propertiesOrderChanges.push(item)
   }
   viewModel.selectedField().properties(propertiesOrderChanges);
 }
});
```

**HTML**:

```
<span>Select a field</span>

<select data-bind='foreach: availableFields, value: selectedField'>
 <option data-bind='text: $data.fieldId, value: $data'></option>
</select>

<div style="padding: 10px">
 <label data-bind='text: "Properties for " + selectedField().fieldId'></label>
<button data-bind='click: $root.addProperty'>Add</button>
<ul id='field-properties-list' data-bind='foreach: selectedField().properties'>
    <li style = "list-style: none;">
        <button data-bind="click: function() {  $root.selectedField().properties.remove($data) }">Delete</button>
        <input data-bind="value: $data.propertyName"></input>
    </li>
</ul>
</div>
```

Comment: Attempting to `delete` a property after performing a `sort` is a little buggy, but the jist is there

Comment: I really don't want to exclude the `ko.computed`'s because they are working well for my purpose. My main problem is linking one of the ko.computed's with the observableArray. I understand your point and I agree that dependency cycles are not healthy and that's why I am trying to break the cycle into chains. For example when the ko.computed will change the value of the obsArray it will not be notified back. And when the obsArray will notify the computed, it will not change the value of the obsArray... when it reevaluates in the read. Thanks

Comment: The problem is that after a `ko.computed` runs the `write` function it calls the `read` function. That's why the cyclic behavior takes place. I am thinking of breaking it with a boolean...

Comment: I added a flag until I will find a smarter way to do it.